# Creating a Chess Game with server connections (java): Will a static board class mess anything up server wise?

Tags: java, chess

I am creating a chess game using Java.
I have a board class which has (mostly) static members.

Its methods include scanning potential piece moves (to check for checks and checkmates) and to print the board and stuff.

Here's an example:

```
public static void scanPositions() {
        for (ChessPiece piece : whitePieces) {
            scanWhitePiece(piece);
        }
        for (ChessPiece piece : blackPieces) {
            scanBlackPiece(piece);
        }
    }

    public static void scanWhitePiece(ChessPiece piece) {
        int[] currentPosition = piece.getCurrentPosition();
        switch (piece.getName()) {
            case "♔":
                ((King) piece).scanning(); //start scanning
                piece.move(currentPosition, null);
                ((King) piece).scanning(); //stop scanning
                break;
            case "♖":
                ((Rook) piece).scanning(); //start scanning
                piece.move(currentPosition, null);
                ((Rook) piece).scanning(); //stop scanning
                break;
            case "♙":
                ((Pawn) piece).scanning(); //start scanning
                piece.move(currentPosition, null);
                ((Pawn) piece).scanning(); //stop scanning
                break;
            default:
                piece.move(currentPosition, null);
                break;
        }
    }
```

A lot of my other classes use the Board because they want to access this class since it contains the getPieces() method, which gives back a 2d array of chessPieces.

So I made these methods static because accessing the Board's current state can be accessed by calling the class using Board.getPieces() rather than constantly passing in a board for every method that uses it.

Just to give an example,
my Pawn, King, BoardScanner (used to check if king is under attack by pieces), and PieceMoves (superclass for moving a piece) all use the board.'

example Pawn: (read the comments)

```
public boolean move(int[] inputPosition, ArrayList<ChessPiece> captures) { //i'd have to constantly pass a ChessPiece[][] board in the methods like this for every method that will use and access the Board. which will be a hassle because many classes use the Board class
        availablePositions = new ArrayList<>();
        if (!scanning) enPassant = false;

        int r = currentPosition[0];
        int c = currentPosition[1];
        int rInput = inputPosition[0];
        int cInput = inputPosition[1];

        if (color.toLowerCase().equals("white")) {
            //one space move
            if (r - 1 >= 0 && Board.getPieces()[r - 1][c] == null) {
                availablePositions.add(new int[] {r - 1, c});
                //starting two space move
                if (starting && r - 2 > 0 && Board.getPieces()[r - 2][c] == null) { //I can just call the Board.getPieces() static stuff here
                    availablePositions.add(new int[] {r - 2, c});
                    if (rInput == r - 2 && cInput == c && !scanning) enPassant = true;
                }
            }
```

Now, the static methods have been working great for me on just a simple terminal version. My question is, will having the board with pretty much all static classes have ramifications for when i put the chess game on a server where players can connect? Because the Board is pretty much owned by the class and isn't dynamic, will this be bad if I somehow start creating multiple chess games that many users can connect to? Should I have designed this Board class as dynamic and just put in the extra step of putting the ChessPiece[][] board in each method parameter that uses the board?

This isn't a question about servers since I am still going to learn how to do that. Right now I'm just wondering if I should make the Board methods dynamic so that I don't have to deal with some sort of domino effect later on.

This is probably a noob question, but I hope someone can help me.

Thank you! :)

Comment: As a side note, the switch statement on chess piece pictures is intriguing to me...haven't seen switches like this yet but I kind of like it...

Comment: Creating/destroying objects is generally more expensive than loading static classes/methods so it might actually help JVM performance on the server

Comment: The question is: if it is running on a server, how many chess games do you expect to be played at the same time? If there is only one chess game running at any one time the static design is not a problem. But if you expect at least two chess games to be played at the same time this approach will no longer work.

Comment: @ThomasKläger I plan on allowing multiple chess games to happen as this is going to be a pet project of mine to test out server stuff. So do you think it's necessary that I make it dynamic because leaving it static will mess up somehow on a server?

Comment: If multiple chess games are allowed to happen at the same time you will need a way to store the board data for each game separate from the board data from the other games. But if the Board class has only static members you effectively have only one board available